# Stricter if statement using regex/beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, if-statement, beautifulsoup

I'm looking for some help making my if statement towards the bottom of this post "stricter" so that it can't by accident return the wrong data.

#### print *`details`*

```
<li class="">
<span class="prefix">Student Discount</span>
                Â£2922.70                </li>
<li class="">
<span class="prefix">Student DiscountX</span>
                5499.99                </li>
```

#### print detail

```
<li class="">
<span class="prefix">Student Discount</span>
                Â£2922.70                </li>
```

#### print unicode(detail)

```
<li class="">
<span class="prefix">Student Discount</span>
                £2922.70                </li>
```

#### BeautifulSoup code snippit

```
details = details_section.findAll('li', {"class":"full"})
for detail in details:
    if detail.find(text=re.compile("Student Discount")):
        SD = detail.get_text().replace("Student Discount", "").strip().replace(u"£", "POUNDSIGNHERE")
        SD = "Student Discount {}".format(detail.get_text().replace("Student Discount", "").strip().replace(u"£", "POUNDSIGNHERE"))
        if not "Student Discount POUNDSIGNHERE" in result_SF:
            SD = "Student Discount POUNDSIGNHERE{}".format(detail.get_text().replace("Student Discount", "").strip().replace(u"£", "POUNDSIGNHERE"))  
        print SD
```

#### Output

```
SF POUNDSIGNHERE2922.70
SF POUNDSIGNHERE5499.99
```

As you can see, I've got around the issue of too many spaces/tabs in each detail and I've replaced the pound symbol with `POUNDSIGNHERE` so that later on when I require it all I have to do is replace it back with the pound symbol.

I'm posting looking for some help changing:
`if detail.find(text=re.compile("Student Discount")):`
To something like:
`if detail.find(text=re.compile('<span class="prefix">Student Discount</span>')):`
or even:
`if detail.find(text=re.compile('>Student Discount<')):`

**I'm wanting to make the if statement stricter so that it couldn't potentially pickup lines like:**

```
<li class="">
<span class="prefix">Student Discount Old</span>
                £2922.70                </li>
```

Any ideas, suggestions or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your example code seems to be incomplete, result_SF is not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just one regex.  Using strip, replace, etc is unnecessary and chaining them like this is confusing.

```
import re
details = details_section.findAll('li', {"class":"full"})
for detail in details:
    detail_text = detail.get_text()
    m = re.match(r"\s*Student Discount\s+£\s*(\d+\.\d+)\s*", detail_text)
    if m:
        discount_value = m.group(1)
        print "discount = " + discount_value
```